# Fullscreen Split View Not Working

Tags: macos, mission-control, fullscreen, split-view

I have read there are two methods of triggering a fullscreen split view - one by pressing and holding the green button and a second by going fullscreen with one app, then dragging and dropping another using mission control. But neither of these work for me - the green button just shows the regular fullscreen and split panes and the mission control method doesn't let me drop anything onto the space.

Are there other methods or fixes for this?

Comment: I suggest to read Apple support document [Use two Mac apps side by side in Split view](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948). By pressing and holding green button pop-up menu should appear and you should make choice from there.

Comment: thanks, I have checked that. I figured part of it out - the accursed Logitech g hub app was interfering with it. Once I disabled it, I was able to get the mission control method working. Still can't get the green button method to work, would appreciate any suggestions.